# The process for getting a patron saint today

Tags: catholicism, patron-saints, roman-curia

For some time now I have been trying to get a patron saint for railroad workers, but I have had little success with various dioceses.

I think my next step should be getting co-signatures, but how many do I need?  World-wide, or would USA suffice?  Hard copy?  Phone numbers?  Addresses?

When the signatures have been gathered, where exactly at the Vatican should I send the letter of intent to?  Should it be addressed to the Congregation for the Causes of Saints?

Comment: Catholicfreeshipping.com (that renowned institution of learning) says that St. John the Baptist is the patron of road workers, close enough?  Probably not.